# How to achieve Side by side with columns in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am new to angular and i am trying to achieve the below data(Array object count is unknown) binding as side by side please give me suggestion source code would be very helpful [image: This is what i want to achieve]

Comment: Generically, I'd look into doing something with CSS and a Flexbox layout.

Comment: Ok sure i will try it out..Is there any possibility to get some familiar source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a grid layout.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
  width: 30ch;
}

.item {
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Array item</div>
  <div class="item">Array item</div>
  <div class="item">Array item</div>
  <div class="item">Array item</div>
  <div class="item">Array item</div>
  <div class="item">Array item</div>
  <div class="item">Array item</div>
  <div class="item">Array item</div>
  <div class="item">Array item</div>
  <div class="item">Array item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that in many different ways.

1. You can just use pure css, and then you can either use [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or flex.
2. Use lib/module, like [basscss](https://basscss.com/) or [@angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) which basically are doing the same and/or more.